# Component with path `*.qml` could not be created

Tags: qt, user-interface, qml, qt-designer, qt-design-studio

I'm using Qt Design Studio and I'm receiving an error:

> Component with path `*.qml` could not be created

[image: Error]

The error is thrown for custom QML types in their own QML files.

However, There is *no* such issue when working with Qt Creator rather than Qt Design Studio.

I have researched and looks like people have run into [similar issues](https://felgo.com/developers/forums/t/troubles-using-designer-in-qt-creator) in 2016.

Is there any solution?

Comment: Did you resolve the issue?

Comment: @NAGARAJS Unfortunately no.